# MVC 5 Route not found if parameter is passed in URL

Tags: asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-5, asp.net-mvc-routing, attributerouting

I have following methods in my MVC controller:

```
[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Add(Guid b)
{
    ViewBag.Title="Add Location";
    //init some info
    return View("Edit",<Model>);
}

[HttpGet]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid l)
{
    ViewBag.Title="Edit Location";
    //get object from db
    return View("Edit",<Model>);
}
```

Following is the route registration:

```
routes.MapRoute(
    name: "Default",
    url: "{controller}/{action}/{id}",
   defaults: new { controller = "Home", action = "Index", id = UrlParameter.Optional }
);
```

Now when I try to access following two routes:

```
1. http://localhost:60732/Location/Add?b=512f770f-51c3-4791-8eba-61fe753e2a83
2. http://localhost:60732/Location/Edit?l=512f770f-51c3-4791-8eba-61fe753e2a83
```

First one works but 2nd gives 404.

I have also tried `AttributeRouting` with following routes:

```
[HttpGet]
[Route("Location/AddLocation/{g}")]
public ActionResult Add(Guid g)

[HttpGet]
[Route("Location/EditLocation/{l}")]
public ActionResult Edit(Guid l)
```

Again,

```
 http://localhost:60732/Location/AddLocation/512f770f-51c3-4791-8eba-61fe753e2a83
```

works but

```
 http://localhost:60732/Location/EditLocation/512f770f-51c3-4791-8eba-61fe753e2a83
```

does not.

What am I doing wrong?

Strangely, if I pass wrong `Guid` like:

```
 http://localhost:60732/Location/EditLocation/512f770f
```

It gives following error:

```
The parameters dictionary contains a null entry for parameter 'l' of non-nullable type
'System.Guid' for method 'System.Web.Mvc.ActionResult Edit(System.Guid)' in
'AppointmentScheduler.Controllers.LocationController'. An optional parameter must be a
reference type, a nullable type, or be declared as an optional parameter.
Parameter name: parameters
```

Comment: I see nothing wrong with this code, it should work. Are we missing something here?

Comment: @DavidG that's what I am not able to figure out. There is nothing fancy there but still it is not working.

Comment: With your edit, it seems the error is originating inside the action method. Does that throw a 404 error or an `HttpNotFound` exception?

Comment: Yes @DavidG it was inside mthod and returned `HttpNotFound`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

There is nothing wrong with your routing here. However, the code in your `Edit` method must itself be throwing a 404 error by throwing `HttpNotFound`.

Answer (score 1):

I just hope this is last WTF of 2014. I pass the id (Guid) and try to fetch object from db. Actually, it is not able to find it and I'm returning: `HttpNotFound` (I think copied from some API method). So I am always getting `404` for this route.